How can I make the symbols in the last line of the formula appear in normal size?
Here is the compiled result

and the code is here
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\det(\boldsymbol \omega(\pi_0), \pi) =
\left|
\frac{\partial(\boldsymbol \omega(\pi))}{\partial(\boldsymbol \omega(\pi_0))}
\right| & = 
\left|
\frac{\partial(\boldsymbol \omega(\pi))}{\partial(\boldsymbol p(\pi))}
\frac{\partial(\boldsymbol p(\pi))}{\partial(\boldsymbol p(\pi_0))}
\frac{\partial(\boldsymbol p(\pi_0))}{\partial(\boldsymbol \omega(\pi_0))}
\right| \\
& = 
\left|
\frac{\partial(\boldsymbol \omega(\pi))}{\partial(\boldsymbol p(\pi))}
\frac{\partial(\boldsymbol p(\pi))}{\partial(u, v)}
\frac{\partial(u, v)}{\partial(\boldsymbol p(\pi_0))}
\frac{\partial(\boldsymbol p(\pi_0))}{\partial(\boldsymbol \omega(\pi_0))}
\right| \\
& = 
\frac{
\left|
\frac{\partial(\boldsymbol \omega(\pi))}{\partial(\boldsymbol p(\pi))}
\frac{\partial(\boldsymbol p(\pi))}{\partial(u, v)}
\right| 
}{
\left|
\frac{\partial(\boldsymbol \omega(\pi_0))}{\partial(\boldsymbol p(\pi_0))}
\frac{\partial(\boldsymbol p(\pi_0))}{\partial(u, v)}
\right| 
}
\end{aligned}
\label{equ_cpt3_6}
\end{equation}

\end{document}

The symbols in the last line appear smaller than those in the other lines. How can I make them appear in normal size?

@DavidCarlisle That works! Thank you, man!

@DavidCarlisle There is also typo in this comment...

@Explorer yes well one was copied to the other, but you can not edit comments, only delete them:-)

they are textstyle as they are in a fraction, but if you are sure you want it you could use
\frac
   {\displaystyle big numerator}
   {\displaystyle big denominator}


There is a typo in \displaystyle

@Explorer oops thanks, fixed
